# How does the common networking application (using unix socket API) accomplish to forward its port, with the computer connected to a internet router?

Tags: c, sockets

Do you happen to know common application using unix socket api doesn't work on computer connected to internet router? For example, assume that there is a computer that is running a simple web server using socket in C. when a web browser in another remoter computer send a request, the web server cannot send a response to the request since its port is closed by the internet router(?) (Of course, there might exist another reasons).

However, the common applications by a competent developers works well. For example, utorrent client receives a request for some data from peers and responds to the request well, although a computer that is running utorrent is connected to the internet router. Does utorrent adjust router configurations using some system calls? If not, how does it upload the some data?

So my question is that

how does common application using socket API accomplish to forward its port, with the connection to the internet router?

How my program in C accomplish to forward its port with computer connected to the internet router?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're asking about NAT Traversal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're connected the internet through a NAT router, in most cases any unsolicited connection into the router from the WAN will be refused. What you need is to tell the router (in some way) that unsolicited traffic coming in on a specific port number or range is to be accepted, and forwarded on towards a specific local IP address. This can either be done manually in your router's configuration, or if your router supports [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal) you can use that protocol to configure port mapping for the traversal of the router.

Answer (score 0):

They don't. To send and receive data on the connections your program has started it's not needed. Port forwarding needs to be done by hand by the machine administrator and is only required to receive new connections.